# React-Virtualizer InfiniteLoader startIndex and stopIndex are the same value

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm using React-Virtualizer, and it seems as if the initial call to load rows has a startIndex of 0 and stopIndex of 0. If the array already has some items, then the startIndex is the array length, and the stopIndex is the same array length. I'm not sure why this is happening, but obviously it's a problem.

You can see a reproducible example here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/TP5BTGNA0Me1Rz7Q7Ge9?p=preview

And here's the JSX file:

```
var List = ReactVirtualized.List;
var InfiniteLoader = ReactVirtualized.InfiniteLoader;
var AutoSizer = ReactVirtualized.AutoSizer;
var CellMeasurer = ReactVirtualized.CellMeasurer;
var CellMeasurerCache = ReactVirtualized.CellMeasurerCache;

// Define a component:
var Main = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      hasNextPage: true,
      nextPageLoading: false,
      totalCount: 100,
    }
  },
  loadNextPage: function({startIndex, stopIndex}) {
    console.log(startIndex, stopIndex) // THIS ISN'T RIGHT?
  },
  render: function() {
      const rows = []
      const rowsCount = this.state.hasNextPage ? rows.length + 1 : rows.length

      // Only load 1 page of items at a time.
      // Pass an empty callback to InfiniteLoader in case it asks us to load more than once.
      const loadMoreRows = this.state.nextPageLoading ? () => {} : this.loadNextPage

      // Every row is loaded except for our loading indicator row.
      const isRowLoaded = ({ index }) => !this.state.hasNextPage || index < rows.length

      // Render a list item or a loading indicator.
      const rowRenderer = ({ index, key, style }) => {
        if (!isRowLoaded({ index })) {
          console.log("LOADING")
          return(
            <div style={style}>
              Loading...
            </div>
          )
        } else {
          console.log(rows[index])
          return(
            <div style={style}>
              {rows[index]}
            </div>
          )
        }
      }

      console.log(rows) // SHOWS THE ARRAY
      return(
        <InfiniteLoader
          isRowLoaded={isRowLoaded}
          loadMoreRows={loadMoreRows}
          rowCount={rowsCount}>
          {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) => (
            <div style={{height: 300}}>
              <AutoSizer>
                {({ height, width }) => (
                  <List
                    height={height}
                    width={width}
                    ref={registerChild}
                    onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                    rowCount={this.state.totalCount}
                    rowHeight={46}
                    rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
                  />
                )}
              </AutoSizer>
            </div>
          )}
        </InfiniteLoader>
      );
  }
});


// Render your list
ReactDOM.render(
    <Main />, // What to render (an instance of the Main component)
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This wound up being because the rowCount was set to the current length rather than the total that it would be after all data was loaded. Setting it to the total list size from the server fixed it.